# Why does height - number return string?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In my [p5js](https://p5js.org/reference/#p5/rect) draw function, there is a variable, `height`, which is the height of the canvas. If I call `typeof height` it returns `number`. However, using `rect(0, (height - 20), width, 20);` returns the error:

> `p5.js says: rect() was expecting Number for parameter #1 (zero-based index), received string instead`

But `typeof (height - 20)` returns number. So why's the error occuring?

A live demo should be [here](https://editor.p5js.org/William3142/sketches/9f-GqO39g). Peculiarly however, the error doesn't appear to show in the console on there. I think this is because it's not explicitly logged and things work different in the Web Editor.

Comment: put `rect(0, (height - 20), width, 20);` into a variable, and `console.log` it just before you pass it to the draw function, my guess is the height and or width sometimes aren't numbers (maybe `undefined`?). Can you make a reproduced example so we can see it in action?

Comment: Using `let ground = rect(0, (height - 20), width, 20);` and logging `ground` gives me a long object, presumably derived from p5js itself. Live example should be [here](https://editor.p5js.org/William3142/sketches/9f-GqO39g)

Comment: Confused by this: _rect() was expecting Number for parameter #1_ yet the question is somehow about `height` (which is part of parameter #2). Clarify?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I believe it is using a zero-based index, shown in the error?

Comment: thanks. didn't interpret it that way.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error?

Answer (score -2):

In my case, it was due to one of the variables used in the `arc/rect` function that had been declared using "var". Changed it to "let" and everything worked like a charm.